# Sending email via sendgrid from CakePHP Shell returns response code 0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, sendgrid

I have been exploring [sendgrid's](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) web api and sent email (**response code 202**) using their api from a controller of **CakePHP** but I need to send email via [shell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/shells.html) so I have written a shell in **CakePHP** but same code returns response code 0!

Am I missing something ? Help will be appreciated.Thanks

Here's the code .

```
$apiKey = 'myapikey';
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("a@gmail.com", "SendGrid");
$email->setSubject("Testing sendgrid php api");
$email->addTo("b@gmail.com", "user");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "Hello");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
   try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    $this->out($response->statusCode());

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->out($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Does Sendgrid give you any further information in the response about why it failed?

Comment: @MarkStory Nope , it didn't .I have no clue why it's not working if I run the codes via shell. what if  php as a user should run the shell ?

Comment: HTTP requests generally are far enough away from the local OS that permissions shouldn't be a problem. Unless your PHP CLI setup disallows outgoing HTTP requests.

Comment: Their [API example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/php.html), which your code seems to be edited from, indicates that `$response->headers()` and `$response->body()` should have more information for you?